# What are these dark green, leafy, vegetable plants?

Tags: identification, vegetables

[image: Vegetable 1]

[image: Vegetable 2]

I think at least one of them is kale?

Comment: First is kale. Second looks like some kind of cabbage.

Comment: Thanks. The texture of the second vegetable does feel like cabbage.

Comment: I'm not convinced about the first being kale, yet (what kind?), but the second certainly does look like cabbage. @ThatIdiot

Answer (score 1):

The top plant resembles some pictures I was able to find of Lacinato Kale, which lacks the curly leaf edges of the more familiar Curly Kale varieties.

The lower plants are almost certainly some manner of [Brassica oleracea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brassica_oleracea) but that is an impressively wide species. Because of it's youth it could be cauliflower, broccoli, cabbage, brussel sprouts or almost any other cultivar within the species. Time will tell what that plant is.

Comment: The second one looks like a young [red cabbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_cabbage), judging by the color. The nerves are purple instead of white (like cauliflower), which rules out quite a couple of cultivars.